# Using states in linearity of expectation (basic example to solidify conceptual understanding)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to learn about linearity of expectation and looking at using states to solve problems. This is a very basic example but I do not understand the final steps in the solution outlined below. In bold I've added some of my own assumptions and pointed out areas which I'm having trouble understanding.

> Allison has an unfair coin which lands on heads with probability $p$.  What is the expected value for the number of times she will have to flip the coin until she flips a heads?

Let's define two states: we have either not flipped a head yet (state $0$) or we have flipped a head (state $1$).

Let $E[X_i]$ denote the expected number of flips needed to complete the process. Clearly, $E[X_1]=0$, since state $1$ means we have flipped a head and the process is complete. On the other hand, once we flip in state $0$, we will remain in state $0$ with probability $1-p$ and we will move to state $1$ with probability $p$.

Then, considering our state after the first flip in state $0$, we have:

$E[X_0]=1+(1-p)\cdot E[X_0]+p\cdot E[X_1]$

**My thought here is we can simplify this to:**

$E[X_0]=1+(1-p)\cdot E[X_0]+p\cdot 0$

$E[X_0]=1+(1-p)\cdot E[X_0]$

**but now the solution says that this yields the result:**

$p\cdot E[X_0]=1$, giving $E[X_0]=\frac{1}{p}$.

**What am I missing? I can't seem to get from here**
$E[X_0]=1+(1-p)\cdot E[X_0]$
**to here$E[X_0]=\frac{1}{p}$**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just algebraic manipulations:
\begin{align*}
E[X_0]&=1+(1-p)\cdot E[X_0] \\
E[X_0]&=1+E[X_0]-p\cdot E[X_0]\\
0&=1-p\cdot E[X_0]\\
p\cdot E[X_0]&=1\\
E[X_0]&=\frac{1}{p}.
\end{align*}